# InternetExplorer.Application object and cookie container

Tags: internet-explorer, cookies, automation

I have the following console application written in VB.NET:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim ie As Object = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.Navigate2("http://localhost:4631/Default.aspx")
End Sub
```

This program uses the [InternetExplorer.Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752084(VS.85).aspx) automation object to launch an IE window and navigate a given url. The problem that I encountered is that even if I launch multiple instances of my application, the IE windows that are created with this method all share the same cookie container. Is there any parameter I could use specifying that a different cookie container is created for every window?

This is the web page I used to test cookies:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<script runat="server">
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Store something into the session in order to create the cookie
        Session["foo"] "bar";
        Response.Write(Session.SessionID);
    }
</script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server"></form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With respect of `CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")` you create an instance of Internet Explorer and all instances of you program communicate through this one process. **Cookies will be hold per process**.

You can try to use in your application `WebBrowser` control instead (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s8ys666.aspx). You find in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752044(VS.85).aspx information which compare two ways. If you will use `WebBrowser` control in you application all instances of your application will have his own set of cookies, but only one set of cookies per process independent on the number of `WebBrowser` controls in your application.

Inside of any process you can any time clear the cookie with respect of following call

```
InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, INTERNET_OPTION_END_BROWSER_SESSION, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
```

(see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/195192/en) which shows one more time the nature of cookies holding.