# InternetExplorer.Application with -nomerge switch?

Tags: .net, internet-explorer

I'm trying to create a InternetExplorer.Application object, but I want IE to start with the -nomerge switch.  Is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Similar question asked  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503041/internetexplorer-application-object-and-cookie-container) a while ago & it doesn't seem possible with the usual InternetExplorer.Application object; the answer posted suggested either using WebBrowser or alternative ways of clearing session cookies

However there's also another option that would have a similar effect using the InPrivate mode - if you're using VB.NET

From visualbasic.about.com:

> In VB.NET, you can add a reference to ShDocVw.dll (in Windows/System32) using the Browse > tab in Add Reference) and open an instance of IE 8 using the new "InPrivate" mode.

```
> Dim TheBrowser = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorerMedium   
> TheBrowser.Visible = True  
> TheBrowser.Navigate( _  
> URL:="http://visualbasic.about.com")
```