# Opening IE InPrivate Mode

Tags: javascript

I need to open an instance of IE using `InPrivate` mode but then open 2 pages in tabs within that instance. I've been at it for 2 days and I have it opening 2 separate `IE` windows with the pages I want but I can not find the commends I need to use to open both pages in the same window.

Here's my JS that sort of works

```
var oShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
oShell.run("\"%ProgramFiles%\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore\" -private http://www.yahoo.com");
oShell.run("\"%ProgramFiles%\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore\" -private http://www.google.com");
```

I found this page that I thought would help but I can't seem to grasp what is being suggested or the commands that are needed.

[InternetExplorer.Application with -nomerge switch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686228/internetexplorer-application-with-nomerge-switch)

Comment: I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/427479/programmatically-open-new-pages-on-tabs (see the voted answer).